# Swagger ui issue when upgrading handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js, swagger-ui

I have swagger-ui.js version 2.1.2 which is working with handlebars v2.0.0

I upgraded handlebars to 4.7.7 now my swagger-ui is not working with error:

```
Template was precompiled with an older version of Handlebars than the current runtime.
```

I am not familiar with swagger UI I just need to upgrade this library due to vulnerability issue. Anyone knows which swagger-ui.js version is compatible with which handlebars.js version? Or can point me to documentation that I can read regarding this.